# how to use after insertion triggers in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| _date  | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| petrol | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| diesel | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gas    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| _date1  | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| petrol1 | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| diesel1 | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gas1    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I am new at triggers and SQL overall and wanted to use after insert trigger such that once i enter values in the table "buy" mentioned above. The same value inserted must be inserted into the "Sell" table(also mentioned above) but after a mathematical operation :

```
petrol+petrol*0.3, diesel+diesel*0.15, gas+gas*0.25
```

I tried to use this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1
AFTER INSERT
ON buy
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
(
    INSERT INTO Sell (_date1, petrol1, diesel1, gas1)
    SELECT _date, petrol+petrol*0.3, diesel+diesel*0.15, gas+gas*0.25
    FROM inserted
)
END
```

But then, it showed this error below:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'after insert
>   on buy
>   for each row
>   begin
>   (insert into Sell (_date1, petrol1, diese' at line 1

Comment: Your trigger does not look at all like a MySQL trigger.

Comment: Which version of MySQL is this?

Comment: @wallyk . . . Nothing in the documentation refers to `inserted`.  And nothing in the trigger refers to `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger t1 after insert on buy for each row
begin
    insert into Sell (_date1, petrol1, diesel1, gas1)
        values (new._date, new.petrol * 1.3, new.diesel * 1.15, new.gas * 1.25)
end;$$

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Your Referenced MySQL 8 Document page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Read down you will find the following two statements:

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access
>   columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL
>   extensions to triggers; they are not case-sensitive.
>
> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old
>   row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no
>   new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of the row after it is updated.

So with that I entirely agree with @Gordon Linoff

What you're looking for is:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER t1 AFTER INSERT ON buy FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Sell (_date1, petrol1, diesel1, gas1)
    VALUES (NEW._date, NEW.petrol * 1.3, NEW.diesel * 1.15, NEW.gas * 1.25);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```